# Equivalent to Lambda Expressions in Python

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming

A common operation I perform is joining a list of lists of letters into a list of words (strings).

I normally use a list comprehension:

```
lists_of_letters = [["m", "y"], ["d", "o", "g"], ["s", "k", "i", "p"]]
list_of_words = ["".join(a_list_of_letters) for a_list_of_letters in lists_of_letters]
# list_of_words == ["my", "dog", "skip"]
```

Or sometimes a little more functional:

```
list_of_words = map(lambda x: "".join(x), lists_of_letters)
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to write the function needed for the map call than using a lambda expression. I'm trying to learn the [operator](http://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) and [functools](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) to expand my python functional programming chops, but I can't seem to find a clear way to use them in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case you can actually just say `map(''.join, lists_of_letters)`:

```
In [1]: lists_of_letters = [["m", "y"], ["d", "o", "g"], ["s", "k", "i", "p"]]
In [2]: map(''.join, lists_of_letters)
Out[2]: ['my', 'dog', 'skip']
```

because `''.join` is itself a function (a bound method on the empty string) that takes a single argument:

```
In [3]: ''.join
Out[3]: <built-in method join of str object at 0x100258620>
```

That said, here it may not be better *per se* because it's a bit less readable IMO

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot that bound methods were first class functions as well. Thats why I wasn't getting anywhere with _partial_.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the lambda function here:

```
In [26]: map("".join, lists_of_letters)
Out[26]: ['my', 'dog', 'skip']
```